# XSLT Matching 2 Elements to get another

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm relatively new to XSLT but want to perform what I thought was a relatively simple match between elements to get another.

Here is a snippet from the XML. Version = 1.0 and output is text (converting xml to text).

```
<Accounts>
              <Account>
                 <Id>273228MD301</Id>
                 <EPIProductCode>IPP4D3</EPIProductCode>
                 <Name>Mr John Smith</Name>
                 <Status>Open</Status>
                 <Owners>
                    <Owner>
                       <Id>273228M</Id>
                    </Owner>
                 </Owners>
                 <Advisers>
                    <Adviser>
                       <Id>286666</Id>
                       <PrimaryAdviser>true</PrimaryAdviser>
                    </Adviser>
                 </Advisers>
                 <Delete>false</Delete>
                 <LastModified>2012-06-08T15:19:19</LastModified>
              </Account>
              <Account>
                <Id>273228MD399</Id>
                <EPIProductCode>IPAAA</EPIProductCode>
                <Name>Sir Leslie Patterson</Name>
                <Status>Open</Status>
                <Owners>
                    <Owner>
                        <Id>2732299</Id>
                    </Owner>
                </Owners>
                <Advisers>
                   <Adviser>
                        <Id>286666</Id>
                <PrimaryAdviser>true</PrimaryAdviser>
                </Adviser>
                </Advisers>
                <Delete>false</Delete>
                <LastModified>2012-06-08T15:19:19</LastModified>
              </Account>
              <Account>
                <Id>273228MD999</Id>
                <EPIProductCode>IPYYY</EPIProductCode>
                <Name>Dame Edna</Name>
                <Status>Open</Status>
                <Owners>
                   <Owner>
                      <Id>27322YY</Id>
                   </Owner>
                </Owners>
                <Advisers>
                   <Adviser>
                      <Id>286666</Id>
                      <PrimaryAdviser>true</PrimaryAdviser>
                   </Adviser>
                </Advisers>
                <Delete>false</Delete>
                <LastModified>2012-06-08T15:19:19</LastModified>
                 </Account>
                </Accounts>
<InvestmentHoldingBalances>
              <HoldingBalance>
                 <AccountId>273228MD399</AccountId>
                 <InvestmentCode>TEST123</InvestmentCode>
                 <Exchange>FND</Exchange>
                 <UnitBalance>
                    <Settled Currency="AUD">0</Settled>
                    <Pending Currency="AUD">0</Pending>
                    <AsAtDate>2012-06-08T15:19:34</AsAtDate>
                 </UnitBalance>
                 <LastModified>2012-05-16T00:00:00</LastModified>
              </HoldingBalance>
              <HoldingBalance>
                 <AccountId>273228MD301</AccountId>
                 <InvestmentCode>0114AU</InvestmentCode>
                 <Exchange>FND</Exchange>
                 <UnitBalance>
                    <Settled Currency="AUD">0</Settled>
                    <Pending Currency="AUD">0</Pending>
                    <AsAtDate>2012-06-08T15:19:34</AsAtDate>
                 </UnitBalance>
                 <LastModified>2012-05-16T00:00:00</LastModified>
              </HoldingBalance>
              <HoldingBalance>
                 <AccountId>273228MD301</AccountId>
                 <InvestmentCode>0016AU</InvestmentCode>
                 <Exchange>FND</Exchange>
                 <UnitBalance>
                    <Settled Currency="AUD">0</Settled>
                    <Pending Currency="AUD">0</Pending>
                    <AsAtDate>2012-06-08T15:19:34</AsAtDate>
                 </UnitBalance>
                 <LastModified>2012-05-16T00:00:00</LastModified>
              </HoldingBalance>
              <HoldingBalance>
                 <AccountId>273228MD301</AccountId>
                 <InvestmentCode>0277AU</InvestmentCode>
                 <Exchange>FND</Exchange>
                 <UnitBalance>
                    <Settled Currency="AUD">0</Settled>
                    <Pending Currency="AUD">0</Pending>
                    <AsAtDate>2012-06-08T15:19:34</AsAtDate>
                 </UnitBalance>
                 <LastModified>2012-05-15T00:00:00</LastModified>
              </HoldingBalance>
              <HoldingBalance>
                 <AccountId>273228MD999</AccountId>
                 <InvestmentCode>TD0155</InvestmentCode>
                 <Exchange>FND</Exchange>
                 <UnitBalance>
                    <Settled Currency="AUD">0</Settled>
                    <Pending Currency="AUD">0</Pending>
                    <AsAtDate>2012-06-08T15:19:34</AsAtDate>
                 </UnitBalance>
                 <LastModified>2012-05-21T00:00:00</LastModified>
              </HoldingBalance>
           </InvestmentHoldingBalances>
```

What I'm tying to do is match nodes //Accounts/Account/Id with //InvestmentHoldingBalances/HoldingBalance/AccountId and when there is a match get the corresponding //Owners/Owner/Id that belongs to that Account Id.
The results Im getting when I do a match is the first //Owners/Owner/Id for all rows not the individual matching one. This is my xslt;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<!--  Create Header Record -->
<xsl:template match="xxxxxx">
<!-- Some other xslt here to extract header info -->
 <xsl:apply-templates select="InvestmentHoldingBalances/HoldingBalance" />  
</xsl:template> 

<!-- Create HoldingBalance Records -->
<xsl:template match="HoldingBalance">
<xsl:value-of select="AccountId" />
<xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="InvestmentCode" />
<xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Exchange" />
<xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="../../Accounts/Account/Id=AccountId">
  <xsl:value-of select="../../Accounts/Account/Owners/Owner/Id" />
 </xsl:if>   
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#10;</xsl:text> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is the same Owner Id for each row (ie '273228M' the last column), not the matching Owner Id according to the Account Id match;

```
273228MD399","TEST123","FND","273228M"
273228MD301","0114AU","FND","273228M"
273228MD301","0016AU","FND","273228M"
273228MD301","0277AU","FND","273228M"
273228MD999","TD0155","FND","273228M"
```

The result I'm after would look like this;

```
273228MD399","TEST123","FND","2732299"
273228MD301","0114AU","FND","273228M"
273228MD301","0016AU","FND","273228M"
273228MD301","0277AU","FND","273228M"
273228MD999","TD0155","FND","27322YY"
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is in the

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../Accounts/Account/Owners/Owner/Id"/>
```

The select expression selects *all* owner ids in the whole document regardless of the account id, and when you ask for the `value-of` a set of more than one node the result is defined by the spec to be the value of the first node in the set in document order.

You need to somehow constrain the set to just the matching accounts, the easiest way to do this is

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../Accounts/Account[Id = current()/AccountId]/Owners/Owner/Id"/>
```

but it is likely to be more efficient to define a *key* at the top level of the stylesheet (put it directly after the `xsl:output` element)

```
<xsl:key name="accountById" match="Account" use="Id"/>
```

Then you can extract the right account in the `value-of` using

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('accountById', AccountId)/Owners/Owner/Id"/>
```

Either way, you don't actually need the `if` around the `value-of`, because in the case where no accounts match the current `AccountId` you'll be asking for the `value-of` an empty node set, which is the empty string by definition.

And finally, you should never need `disable-output-escaping` when you are using `<xsl:output method="text"/>` - simply `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` will work just as well here.

Comment: @user2356926 glad it helped, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that when you get an answer that solves your problem it's a good idea to _accept_ it by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer so others can see at a glance that the problem is solved.